# Listen to google sheets cell change

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there any way to listen to a change event on Google Spreadsheets cells?
I'm writing a web app using AngularJS and Node.js. My goal is to query the raw of the cell that changed.

Comment: Take a look at Google Spreadsheets API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: I know of no API that will pickup a "change event", but "Google Spreadsheets API" will let you read/write raw cell contents. PS, if you find a way to pickup a Change event, I would love to know.

Comment: Maybe I can build something using google app script?